How to add new items to nested list after a specified item in Python?
Given list is this.
list1 = [10, 20, [300, 400, [5000, 6000], 500], 30, 40]
Expected Output is this. I know it is so basic question but I am confused.
Output:
[10, 20, [300, 400, [5000, 6000, 7000], 500], 30, 40]
I want anyone to helo me to solve this. And also explain the insert function with nested list.

append to the element you want:
In [1]: list1 = [10, 20, [300, 400, [5000, 6000], 500], 30, 40]

In [2]: list1[2][2]
Out[2]: [5000, 6000]

In [3]: list1[2][2].append(7000)

In [4]: list1
Out[4]: [10, 20, [300, 400, [5000, 6000, 7000], 500], 30, 40]



list1 = [10, 20, [300, 400, [5000, 6000], 500], 30, 40]

list1[2][2].insert(2, 7000)


The insert method adds an element at a specified position in the list. The syntax is list.insert(index, element), where index is the position where you want to insert the element, and element is the element you want to add.
In the above code:
list1[2][2] refers to the nested list [5000, 6000].
insert(2, 7000) adds 7000 at the index 2 (which is the end of the list in this case).

You can do this:
list1 = [10, 20, [300, 400, [5000, 6000], 500], 30, 40]

# Access the innermost list
innermost_list = list1[2][2]

# Insert 7000 into the innermost list
innermost_list.append(7000)

print(list1)  

Output: [10, 20, [300, 400, [5000, 6000, 7000], 500], 30, 40]
